# I want to perform time range search on date range in azure search

Tags: c#, azure-search-.net-sdk

I want to perform time range search in azure indexing search,date range search is already working fine. but now i want to search records for example

```
DateTimeFrom :  09/01/2018 09:00 AM
DateTimeTo :    09/30/2018 05:00 PM
```

I am passing dates from and to in azure indexing search, It is working fine. and if i pass one day with time range it is also working fine. but when i select date range more than 1 day and set time range for data, it does not apply the time range search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by myself. I get records from azure in specific time range and then filter day by day using foreach loop in c#. so that i can get day wise time range records. which solves my problems.